# ttdbserver and inetd

Tags: aix, inetd

If I disable ttdbserver service in an AIX server (I commented the line with `#` in `/etc/inetd.conf`):

```
#ttdbserver    sunrpc_tcp      tcp     wait    root    /usr/dt/bin/rpc.ttdbserver rpc.ttdbserver 100083 1
```

is it necessary to restart daemons with inetd restart command, to apply changes?

Comment: [Securing AIX Network Services](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/aix/aix.html)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're talking about restarting **`inetd`**.

That's done so that **`inetd`** is forced to examine its configuration and not attempt to restart "stopped" daemons.

The [manual page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.networkcomm/tcpip_daemons_inetd.htm) says to send a "kill -1" (or do "refresh -s inetd"):

> edit /etc/inetd.conf then
>   run refresh -s inetd or
>   kill -1 inetd *PID*

Answer (score 0):

Comment-out the `ttdbserver` service line in `/etc/inetd.conf` and restart the `inetd` daemon by sending `kill -HUP <pid_of_inetd>`.  This re-reads the `inetd` configuration.

Look for and kill any `rpc.ttdbserver` processes.  No new ones will now respawn.